# How to hide overlapping mesh to weight paint correctly?

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, selection-tools

[image]

Hi I'm still new to blender and am not sure how to go about selecting this properly.

You see, the toes of the character overlap. I tried hiding with "H" like I saw on another question, but I don't know how to select the faces of the right toe that are inside the left toe without selecting the left toe faces/vertices.

I saw a youtube video about pressing ctrl+l when "hovering" over a face that's selected, but it's not selecting the whole remaining portion of the right toe like I thought it would.

Comment: It's hard to see what is going on in the screenshot. Do you need all these *Sharp Edge* marks (cyan-colored edges)? You can select the menu entry *Edge > Clear Sharp* in *Edit* mode to remove them. Ctrl+L selects linked element. If your mesh has no loose parts that are disconnected from other loose parts this will select the whole mesh. You could try to select the tip of the toe and then use *Select > Select Less/More > More* (*Ctrl* + *Numpad+*) to select more vertices of the toe.

Comment: What ended up working was instead of selecting faces(since they would stop continuing to highlight with numpad+, I used vertex selection and had to go into the left foot's toe to select the right foot's toe's vertices and used numpad + to select the faces inside and hide them. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also forgot to mention, I was able to weight paint fine after going to weight paint mode-->at the top select vertex selection and it hides the mesh, then just ctrl+left click the bone and done. rinse and repeat and now both toes can move freely(the original downloaded mesh had them overlapping).